# Hyperlink text change without effect of other links like title text, popular post and etc

Tags: css, templates, blogs, blogger

I want to change the text color of a hyperlink in a single post because it is similar to other text and i am using blogger with a customized theme. The issue is when I change my link text color with CSS

```css
a { color: yellow;}
```

its change my whole website links color so please help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance
[My website link](https://pakostdramalyrics.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Try a:nth-child(n) where n is the number for that anker tag

Comment: not working a:nth-child(n) is working similar to a

Comment: Give that anker tag an id then apply css to it.

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: @Usman i am not able to find anker tag no where i can find that

Comment: By anker tag I mean 'a' tag.

Comment: @Usman by doing this a:nth-child(n) its not working but someone here suggest me to do by adding class or id but i am not alble to find the code of concer can you please me to find that code for add class or id. here is struture of my hyperlink text  <a href="https://pakostdramalyrics.blogspot.com/search/label/Hum%20Tv" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-decoration-line: none;">Hum Tv</a></span></span><br>

Comment: `<a href="pakostdramalyrics.blogspot.com/search/label/Hum%20Tv" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-decoration-line: none;color:red">Hum Tv</a>`. Now I add `color:red` property to the link. Now, check this out.

Comment: @Usman I have done that but it's only for a single page. I want for my whole blog when I search that code in edit HTML in blog XML code, then I am not able to find that code in XML.

Comment: `<a class="changeColor" href="pakostdramalyrics.blogspot.com/search/label/Hum%20Tv" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-decoration-line: none;color:red">Hum Tv</a>`. Now I add class to this tag. Now in your CSS file include these lines of code `.changeColor {color: red}`

Comment: thank you so much for your help but you are not getting my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) or [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) in CSS.

An example:

```css
.pink-link {
  color: pink;
}

#red-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="">First Link</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="" class="pink-link">Coloured Link (class)</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="" id="red-link">Coloured Link (id)</a>
```